# How to animate an object to dissapear (clipped progressively) as it passes through a plane?

Tags: animation, effects

I want to create the effect of a train traveling through a glass plane and becoming progressively invisible as it passes through.
How would you set this up to animate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This answer is only convenient if your object is made of a single (or just a few) materials, and if the plane it intersects is parallel to two cartesian axes:

[image]

All you need to do is to *Mix* your material (in this case, a simple principled shader) with a fully white *Transparent BDSF*.

The *Mix Factor* must be controlled by a *Math > (Greater/Less) than* node, that compares your object's *Geometry > Separate XYZ > [selected coordinate]* with a fixed value.

In this example, *Z* is compared with *0*:

[image]

Additional notes:

- If you are using *Cycles* and you see some black spots, you may need to increase a bit the number of *Transmission* bounces under *Render > Light Paths*.
- If you are using *EEVEE*, your material's setting should have *Blend Mode* and *Shadow Mode* set to *Alpha Clip*.

Comment: I also want to do a billboard with multiple posters disappearing as they move up or down. Will this method work?

Comment: This would work for everyting (in render/rendered mode: the objects always stay visible in solid mode), but the *Mix* must be applied to all the materials involved!